# Error when trying to run RSPEC. Why?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I can't figure out why my RSPEC isn't working. I reinstalled RSPEC with sudo gem install rspec and then tried again to install with a specific version number (`sudo gem install rspec -v 2.11.0`)

I continue to get the following error message and I cannot figure out what it means. I believe that I may or may not have version 1 also installed, not sure.

```
Castillo$ rspec document_spec.rb
```

> /Users/Castillo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `require': no such file to load -- document (LoadError)   from
>   /Users/Castillo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`
>   require'     from /Users/Castillo/Desktop/document_spec.rb:1:in `<top
>   (required)>'  from
>   /Users/Castillo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in`load'    from
>   /Users/Castillo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'    from
>   /Users/Castillo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in`map'     from
>   /Users/Castillo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'     from
>   /Users/Castillo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in`run'   from
>   /Users/Castillo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in
>   `run'     from
>   /Users/Castillo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in`
>   block in autorun'

Comment: Well, does /Users/Castillo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb exist?

Comment: Why is it asking for that? What is that? The .rb file I'm using rspec on never requires "custom_require". The only require method I use is to require the document.rb that I am testing for which is saved on my Desktop (document_spec.rb is also saved on my Desktop.) Are you saying I should just go in there and create a blank custom_require.rb file?

Comment: @Tamar: Of course, it does exist, how else could there be an error on line 36 of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add full path to your `document.rb` file into spec file 
or use 
`require_relative`
or

```
require File.expand_path('../document.rb', __FILE__)
```

Comment: One more question: Is there a reason why I need to use require_relative? Is there something I can change in my settings so that I no longer need to use relative each and every time?

Comment: nope, it is just the way it works, but you can add your folder to ruby load paths: `$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)`